# Does Time Machine support APFS?

Tags: time-machine, disk-utility, external-disk, apfs

I just updated to macOS High Sierra. What's the best way to use Time Machine under Apple's new APFS file system. Should I use Disk Utility to convert my external Time Machine volume to APFS?

Comment: Any news if Mojave's Time Machine supports APFS as destination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Big Sur, macOS now supports Time Machine backups to APFS formatted drives!  The TM backups with APFS are much faster than they were before.  Good luck!
Per the [macOS User Guide](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mh15139/mac) on Apple's website:
APFS or APFS Encrypted disks are the preferred format for a Time Machine backup disk. If you select a new backup disk that’s not already formatted as an APFS disk, you get the option to erase and reformat it. If the disk is a Mac OS Extended format disk that contains an existing Time Machine backup, you aren’t asked to erase and reformat the disk.

Answer (score 31):

Time Machine supports APFS as a source and not a destination. You can't backup to an APFS destination disk and Time Machine will inform you that the disk needs to be HFS+ if you attempt to do this.

Right now, there's nothing you need to or should do. Your internal disk has been converted to APFS and your backup disk is still on HFS+, so Time Machine will function as it always has, and will continue to inherit previous backups despite the difference in format. On a future date when Time Machine supports APFS destinations, you can convert your backup disk.

Answer (score 3):

Until Time Machine is updated, it does not support APFS on the backup disks.

Apple needs to resolve the linkage to folders first. Hard links to directories are not supported in Time Machine, Apple will need to reprogram TM. I'm sure when they have Time Machine updated, they will make the change to APFS seamless.

Answer (score -3):

According to Apple's web site:

> You don't need to change any Time Machine
>   settings to back up APFS-formatted disks. Any Time Machine share
>   points must be shared over SMB instead of AFP.

I wouldn't format your backup drive: it doesn't support APFS unless it is all flash. I would just try to do a Time Machine backup and let it worry about it. Since Time Machine backup are not image backups, I am assuming that the OS will handle the reading and writing of the backup records.

Comment: APFS supports Flash as well as spinning disks! The only thing currently not supported is the Fusion Drive! Also: the question is centered on APFS as **backup destination** file system.

Comment: That's true, but Time Machine will not back up to a APFS volume. So my advice to not format the Time Machine disk still holds and the downvote is unwarranted.

Comment: @ klanomath: under technical aspects ASPF supports spinning disks, but Apple doesn´t.... ( https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208018 ) The most common format for a Time Machine backup disk is Mac OS Extended (Journaled) format. Other supported formats see: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202784